# Plugin Workspace: when to close an OleDbDataReader?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, esri-geodatabase, interoperability

I'm developing a plugin workspace for ArcGIS.  Internally, the plugin uses an OleDBconnection.  All of the [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.aspx) I see seems to stress the importance of closing and disposing the connection.

When the client retrieves all rows from my plugin cursor, this is not a problem - when [OleDBDataReader.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read.aspx) returns false, I close the connection and set [IPluginCursorHelper.IsFinished](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IsFinished_Method/002500000646000000/) to true.

However, in the case where the client *doesn't* retrieve all of the rows I am not able to find an appropriate place to close the connection.

**Since the client is required to call `ReleaseCOMObject` when he's finished with the cursor, is there some way the plugin cursor could be informed of this event and close the <del>OleDBConnection</del> OleDbReader if it is still open?**

I tried implementing IDisposable, but ArcGIS doesn't call dispose.  I tried using a [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx), but when I try to close the connection there I get an exception saying "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used."

**Update**

After having no luck with the COM hacks offered in the comments, I changed my code so that now the [IPluginDatasetHelper](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IPlugInDatasetHelper_Interface/00250000064m000000/) is responsible for opening the OleDBConnection the first time a cursor is requested.  It passes the open connection the cursor's constructor, which keeps it as a member variable.  Now the problem is this: **how can the IPluginDatasetHelper close the OleDBConnection?**

Fortunately, the issue is no longer anywhere nearly as urgent - *apparently **only one instance** of the IPluginDatasetHelper ever gets created*.  The test code below works without a memory leak, *and the IPluginDatasetHelper's constructor only gets called once*.  When justone is true, the test code would show severe memory leakage when the cursor is responsible for opening the connection and `justOne` true.  With the dataset helper responsible for opening the connection and justOne true it climbs to 200MB and stabilizes.  Still, it would be nice to know where to close the connection in the dataset helper.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriGeoDatabase.MyPluginWorkspaceFactory");
    var factory = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IWorkspaceFactory;
    var fws = factory.OpenFromFile(dbcPath,0) as IFeatureWorkspace;
    var fc = fws.OpenFeatureClass(tableName);
    IFeatureCursor fCur = fc.Search(null, false);
    IFeature feat;

    while ((feat = fCur.NextFeature()) != null)
    {
        if (justone)
            break;
    }    
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(fCur);
}
```

**Update 2**

Running the test in the VS debugger, I get this rather strange exception.  I'm hoping it is a result of running it in the debugger from a console exe and will not happen within arcmap. (10000 iterations for test loop).

> **ConextSwitchDeadlock was detected.** The CLR has been unable to
>   transition from COM context 0x4cd7fe8 to COM context 0x4cd8158 for 60
>   seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is
>   most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long
>   running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation
>   generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the
>   application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating
>   continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded
>   apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as
>   CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long
>   running operations.

**Update 3**

I've refactored so that the connection is now a member of the Dataset class and an OleDbDataReader is a member of the cursor helper class.  I'm not sure how critical it is to close the connection in the dataset helper.  IPluginDatasetHelper has an `Open` - but no `Close`.  Now the question is how do I close the OleDbDataReader.  (Original question was OleDbConnection.)

Comment: Very interesting question. Looks like no way to handle this is implemented in .NET. There was an interesting discussion going on at stackoverflow: [How to dispose of a NET COM interop object on Release()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724694/how-to-dispose-of-a-net-com-interop-object-on-release). Another one: [Is it possible to intercept (or be aware of) COM Reference counting on CLR objects exposed to COM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223147/is-it-possible-to-intercept-or-be-aware-of-com-reference-counting-on-clr-objec).

Comment: After diving into the linked answers, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6102727/15497) seems to be the most viable option. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6102727/15497) reusable adaptation of the same solution. Would recommend an extensive testing, though, due to the inherent risk given it is essentialy a hack.

Comment: Thanks @PetrKrebs, I implemented the code in the link, but neither NewAddRef nor NewRelease get called.  Both "this one" and "this" are linked to the same answer ... is there another link you intended to insert?

Comment: @PetrKrebs After setting ComVisible(true) for the plugincursorhelper, the NewAddRef is now being called, unfortunately the NewRelease is not being called.  I'm puzzled how ArcGIS handles this when it's not ComVisible.  The plugincursorhelper in the SimplePoint sample is not COM visible.

Comment: Sorry, here's the correct link for the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6905172/15497). It does seem to handle additional interfaces, which could be helpful in your case.

Comment: The techniques you are both describing/linking to will not work because the Plugin infrastructure does not use traditional COM Containment nor Aggregation. It is an ESRI custom voodoo technique. That is why COM visible is false and why the name of the dll matters and why you have to use the esrireg exe and not regsvr32. The esriPlugin.dll's register function has the incantation to look or these conventions and add the registry entries in the right place.

Comment: There is no need for the cursor helper to be exposed to COM via ComVisible(true). The implemented interfaces are defined in COM and visible to COM, while the implementing class does not need to be since it is only instantiated in the internal plugin implementation.

Comment: As far as registration is concerned, can you elaborate? The only thing which moved to XML registration is the association to a component category. Every other COM-related aspect remains unchanged. The whole issue Kirk is facing has nothing to do with neither registration nor COM-visibility at all.

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum Definitely a lot of voodoo going on there. Thanks for looking into this, please see revised question.

Comment: @PetrKrebs When I tested the code in the "second answer", neither of the events fired.  After changing ComVisible to true, the `NewAddRef` would fire but not the `NewRelease`.  This is getting a bit over my head,  please see updated question. Thanks!

Comment: @PetrKrebs Trying to elaborate in < 600 chars.As you already know, COM objects need to have 4 exported methods.The relevant ones for this discussion are DllRegisterServer/DllUnregisterServer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regsvr32 .The COM implementation for those methods is simple - regsvr32 calls them, they register the relevant CoClasses to the registry, add the entries to the right component categories and it is done. The entries added for the coclasses usually say that the implementation for the COM objects are in so and so dll. For Plugin datasources, this is not true.

Comment: If you inspect the registry after your custom plugin dll is registered with the esriregsvr, you will notice that there will be (as expected) entries for the CoClasses. Nevertheless, it will say that the implementation of that CoClass is in the esri Plugin.dll, not on your dll as would be "normal". If you register it with regsvr32, you will not see this (but your plugin will not work). That is COM voodoo (makes sense, but it is not how Containment or Aggregation would work).

Comment: @KirkKuykendall RE: new question. Are you deadlocking on the UI thread? It is marked as an STA thread?

Comment: @Ragi: Thank you, that's interesting information. Still, does that impede in any way with a COM object lifetime management? My take is that Esri's internal implementation does not always call IUnknown.Release on the IPluginCursorHelper at proper times.

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum Yes, it has STAThread.  I got the exception after I ran the test in the debugger and left the cmd.exe window open for a long time waiting for a Console.Readline.  Will test more outside the VS debugger.

Comment: @PetrKrebs yes it does impede the normal COM object lifetime management. In COM, lifetime is handled by IUnknown (AddRef, Release are for that). Remember how the object gets created and everything works even though COM Visible is false? ESRI Voodoo. Probably worthy of a blog post...

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Try doing all your processing in a separate thread that has been initialized with all the ESRI stuff. Don't pass/marshall direct COM objects there, but just native types and recreate the connections on that thread. Always let the UI Thread pump messages.

Comment: @Ragi: The object we are talking about is the plugin cursor helper, right? Let me summarize my thought process: It is the responsibility of the IPluginDatasetHelper implementation to create the cursor helper instances. As such, the cursor helper coclass does not need to be COM-visible, since no COM client needs to instantiate it. That does not mean that the IPluginCursorHelper implementation is not a COM object. The interface derives from IUnknown, hence provides means of controlling the object lifecycle. CLR keeps a CCW for COM clients to reach the interface.

Comment: @Ragi: Now, is there anything wrong in what I stated above? I do not see any voodoo in that, the only problematic thing is how the client of the IPluginCursorHelper instance (which is the ArcGIS plugin infrastructure) behaves in terms of calling AddRef/Release. Let's say I get a reference to an ICursor which ArcGIS implements by eventually making use of the plugin's cursor helper. I would expect that upon releasing the cursor, the cursor helper gets released as well, which does not seem to happen in every case. Hence I believe it is a question of improper object lifetime management.

Comment: @Ragi: If you are willing to elaborate further in a blog post, that would be awesome.

Comment: @Kirk: I am not sure that processing off the main thread is advisable - that would mean the need to spin off a worker thread and marshall all the calls, which is not a good idea in a plugin data source. Anyway, the error you are getting is not an exception, but a MDA warning. It is merely telling you that there may be a problem with your code, which may not be necessarily the case. In many scenarios it is perfectly valid to have a long-running operation in a STA COM server, but you are traditionally expected to keep pumping messages. If you do not do that, the MDA takes that as a sign of

Comment: improper behavior and warns you. The COM clients are kept waiting, but there is not much else you can do when implementing a plugin data source. Note that you can always disable the ConextSwitchDeadlock MDA in VS.

Comment: So very likely there is nothing wrong with your implementation. Switching to MTA is not an option since ArcObjects are generally designed for classic STA model, where cross-apartment calls are marshalled via the message pump. Also resist the temptation to call anything like  Application.DoEvents, because a) it raises a whole bunch of reentrancy issues b) the issue will never manifest itself like this outside the debugging environment.

Comment: @PetrKrebs agreed with everything you said after my comment - even the MTA advice.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to shut the connection down.  Establishing a connection on every cursor pass is not efficient.

Comment: @CraigWilliams Yes, I've changed my logic a bit so now the oledbconnection is a member of the Dataset helper class.  So now the question is how do I release the OledbDataReader which is member of the cursor helper.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, did you find a resolution to your [IGeometryFactory.CreateGeometryFromWkbVariant without generalizing?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/53834/753) question? I noticed you had deleted it but not sure why. I have a [WKT to IGeometry converter class library](https://github.com/blah238/DnrGps_Wkt) that you might find useful (adapted from DnrGps) and just updated it to support spatial references. Could help debugging the issue anyways.

Comment: @blah238  It turned out the geometry factory was a red herring.  I was incorrectly assuming that the geometry passed to [IPluginCursorHelper.QueryShape](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000648000000) would have a null spatialreference. IGeometry.IsEmpty is always true, but when there is a map projection in place it sets a spatial reference.  I resolved by setting the spatialreference to null in my implementation of this method.  Thanks for following up.  Discussion of this is more meaningful in this thread.